# Can someone tell me the update frequency of file "/proc/diskstats"?

Tags: linux

I am doing something to pull the statistics from file /proc/diskstats. I need to know how this file is updated. In a per-second/minute basis or update whenever there's a change? (How does the system know there's a change?) And what's the process that's updating this file constantly? I searched online about this file but all I found was the explanations of these statistics.
My system info is:

## uname -r

2.6.32-431.5.1.el6.x86_64

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `/proc` directory is not a real directory. It is a so-called virtual file system. When you read from a file in that directory you actually access data from kernel memory. So, the kernel maintains the disk statistics. Whenever you read `/proc/diskstats`, you are presented with up-to-date data from the kernel.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So you're saying that whenever there's a statistic change due to disk read/write or some other operations, the kernel memory space that maintains this data is also updated in the same time? Is this updated by some background monitoring process that constantly monitors the data, or by each operation that need to change the statistics?

Comment: My guess is (but I am not a kernel hacker) is that the kernel maintains these statistics with each read and write operation. The overhead of this is probably negligable, so I see no need for a separate monitoring process.